# Turn tail-recursive/iterative procedure into a fully recursive procedure

Tags: recursion, scheme, tail-recursion

I am currently writing a simple program in Scheme which adds numbers together recursively and without using the + operator. Right now I have this program which does what I want to do:

```
(define (add1 x) (+ x 1))

(define (sub1 x) (- x 1))

(define (plus x y) 
  (if (zero? y)
      x
      (plus (add1 x) (sub1 y))
      )
  )
```

However, my tutor has asked me to drop the tail recursion/iteration and write the plus procedure fully recursive. Without telling me too much (this is, after all, a Uni exercise), can you point me in the right direction to figure out how to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you don't want tail recursion, you only need to move the `add1`, but I won't say where. (How does `add1` *not* use `+`? I'm pretty sure it does.)

Comment: tell your tutor that tail recursion is "fully recursive" just the same.

Comment: This is the silliest exercise I've ever heard of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with the comments, it's a silly exercise - your answer is quite fine as it is, it's already a [*tail-recursive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call) solution, which is more efficient than the solution requested by the instructor (which is also recursive, but not *tail* recursive. Calling it *fully* recursive is a misnomer). Anyway, here's a hint:

```
(define (plus x y)
  (if (zero? y) ; the first part remains unchanged
      x
      <???>))   ; now, what do we put here?
```

You have to `add1` at each recursive step, the idea is that you keep adding `1` exactly `y` times, and in the end you add this to `x`. Let me show this with an example, to add `4` plus `3` we do this:

```
(plus 4 3)
```

Which expands to this:

```
(add1 (plus 4 2))
(add1 (add1 (plus 4 1)))
(add1 (add1 (add1 (plus 4 0))))
(add1 (add1 (add1 4)))
```

In the above, `4` was bound to `x` and `3` to `y` at the beginning, and after executing the program we see that `add1` was called three times, the first time we add `1` to `4`, then `1` to `5` and finally `1` to `6`, until we obtain `7`. In other words: the recursive step must call `add1` to the result of *recursively* invoking `plus`, where `x` remains unchanged and `y` is decremented by one unit until it reaches zero, and at this point we reach the base case and the recursion unwinds returning the correct result.

Comment: To add to the silliness (pun intended): `add1` is calling `+`, so anyway we get an expansion that looks like this: `(+ 1 (+ 1 (+ 1 4)))`. So yes, we're using the `+` in the end.

Comment: most probably they intended `add1` to serve as a primitive here. :)

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem by moving the add1 outside the recursive call in the if-block, and passing on x and sub1 y into the recursion.